# SQL-Association table with any level of hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `product` table with following schema

```
     Column     |           Type           |
----------------+--------------------------+
 id             | integer                  |
 name           | character varying(255)   |
```

and a `location` table with schema

```
       Column     |           Type           |
  ----------------+--------------------------+
   id             | integer                  |
   country        | character varying(255)   |
   state          | character varying(255)   |
   region         | character varying(255)   |
   city           | character varying(255)   |
```

I need to have many-to-many relation between the two tables and `product` can be associated with any level of location in `location` table. For example a product can be sold in a whole country or one specific region or city.

I can make entries for all the locations in mapping table if user chooses location at country level(example. if user chooses country US, an entry for all the cities in the US can be made in mapping table) but that would create large number of mapping rows.

What would be the best to map the two table in a way that I can choose any level of location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your third table you can specify the level also. Thus, your third table lets say product_location would have below mentioned fields:

```
product_id
location_name
location_level
```

location_level can have values like country,state ,region,city

For example , your data may look like this:

```
product_id     location_name     location_level
    1             India               Country
    2             New Delhi           City
    3             North Asia          Region
```

Now while selecting you can use the below query:

```
select loc.*,prod.* from location loc, product prod, product_location prodLoc where prodLoc.location_name ='India' and prodLoc.product_id = prod.id and 
case when prodLoc.location_level ='Country' and loc.country= prodLoc.location_name then 'Y'
when prodLoc.location_level ='City' and loc.city= prodLoc.location_name then 'Y'
when prodLoc.location_level ='Region' and loc.region= prodLoc.location_name then 'Y'
else 'N' end ='Y';
```

P.S: This solution has been provided based on the table design provided by you